# excel 2016 combine subtotal with sumifs

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs, subtotal

My SUMIFS needs to add up column D (D11:D172) and the first criteria is a range called qbplistcomp (which is column B so B11:B172) for multiple hits (e.g. CHF, COPD, and all STROKE so using STROKE*) and the second criteria is in column C (C11:C172) looking for the criteria which is a label "qbp volumes" ... so far without subtotaling, this formula works as:

=SUM(SUMIFS(D11:D172,qbplistcomp,{"CHF","COPD","STROKE*"},C11:C172,"QBP Volumes"))
Now my column A has the ability to filter on Category, so if I choose say just "stroke" it should only subtotal (sum) just those ones ... keep getting error ... help, thanks, Tina

Comment: Welcome to SO.. I am not sure but it looks like you want both the functions to work - Sumif when you dont filter the column A and conditional total when you filter Column A.... This may help ....https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria  .. Instead of count use sum...Ok I guess you will have to work on it.. You cant use it directly.

Comment: Also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzjc_eEISe8

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.. Why? It gives us a very multidimensional fomula combining SumIfs and Subtotal.

My examples formula..
`=SUMPRODUCT((A6:A17=A2)*(B6:B17={"North","West","East"})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B6,ROW(B6:B17)-MIN(ROW(B6:B17)),0)))*(C6:C17))`

And hence your formula should be
`SUMPRODUCT((C11:C172="QBP Volumes")*(B11:B172={"CHF","COPD","STROKE*"})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B11,ROW(B11:B172)-MIN(ROW(B11:B172)),0)))*(D11:D172))`

See When the B Col is NOT filtered for "North" C2= 38859 i.e. total for A in North and West
[image]

When the B Col is filtered for "North" C2= 32313 i.e. total for A ONLY in North
[image]

Remember, subtotal formula is applicable to the column you are supposed to filter(Col B). If you intend the same for Col c then replace`(C11:C172="QBP Volumes")` with subtotal formula so your new formula will be `SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(C11,ROW(C11:C172)-MIN(ROW(C11:C172)),0)))*(B11:B172={"CHF","COPD","STROKE*"})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B11,ROW(B11:B172)-MIN(ROW(B11:B172)),0)))*(D11:D172))`