# How to simplify this SUMPRODUCT formula, --(B2:B7="Sunday") + --(B2:B7="Monday")

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I need an array as a filter in a SUMPRODUCT formula. I'd like to pick up either Sunday or Monday in B2:B7 and ignore the rest (this is an simplified example). The formula I have is this:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7="Sunday")+--(B2:B7="Monday"),........)

--(B2:B7="Sunday") gives an array of {1,0,0,0,0,0,0} and --(B2:B7="Monday") gives {0,1,0,0,0,0,0}. The sum of these two arrays is {1,1,0,0,0,0,0}. When used in SUMPRODUCT, this array would filter off others, leaving only Sunday and Monday entries. I wonder if there is a direct way of getting  this array. I have tried --(B2:B7="Sunday","Monday") but it gives a two dimensional array, hence, cannot be used.

[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623143/excel-2016-combine-subtotal-with-sumifs

Comment: Try `(B2:B7={"Sunday","Monday"})`

Comment: @NareshBhople That's a totally valid answer to be posted

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks for the suggestion.. Answer added here.

Answer (score 1):

If we have to check cells in single range for multiple values, as in case of CountIfs, SumIfs SumProduct functions; we can can use `(Range = {"Criteria1","Criteria2"})` argument in the function.

In your case, because you'd like to pick up either Sunday or Monday in B2:B7 and ignore the rest, Try `(B2:B7={"Sunday","Monday"})` So, the function will be `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7={"Sunday","Monday"}),........)`

I learnt this from Tina, a new contributor to SO..
Refer [excel 2016 combine subtotal with sumifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623143/excel-2016-combine-subtotal-with-sumifs/60624509#60624509)

Comment: What I need is exactly the same as the one in the link you provided, namely, multiplication of various terms/arrays.  `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7={"Sunday","Monday"}),........)` would not work because it gives an array of 12 elements while other arrays in SUMPRODUCT have only six elements. Somehow multiplication avoids the problem. So, what is needed is `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7={"Sunday","Monday"})*........)` (note the asterisk instead of comma.)

Comment: It gives array of 12 elements but 2D, 6each*2Col

Comment: Yes, as explained in the link you will need * or , depending on your requirement (sum,count,sumproduct)..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Column2]="Monday")*(Table1[Column4]))+SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Column2]="Sunday")*(Table1[Column4]))`

[image]